# 403 Server failed to authenticate the request while get azure storage data using soapui

Tags: groovy, azure-storage, soapui, azure-table-storage

I am trying to get azure storage table data using soapUI. This is working fine in postman but error occurred while running in soapUI.

**URL using in Postman:**

```
https://storagename.table.core.windows.net/tablename?$filter=CalUId%20eq%20'040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000030D26B53FE24D6010000000000000000100000005CC0FFC3A3676E4CB70214BB089618AE'&sv=2019-10-10&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=2020-06-07T23:32:15Z&st=2020-05-07T15:32:15Z&spr=https&sig=nlrNa1GXTqQPOaKP3X3kDQ056S%2Bwq9Fl1Y%2BTS8A%2FAdQ%3D
```

**Request in SoapUI:**

```
GET https://storagename.table.core.windows.net/tablename?%24filter=CalUId%2520eq%2520%27040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000030D26B53FE24D6010000000000000000100000005CC0FFC3A3676E4CB70214BB089618AE%27&sv=2019-10-10&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=2020-06-07T23%3A32%3A15Z&st=2020-05-07T15%3A32%3A15Z&spr=https&sig=nlrNa1GXTqQPOaKP3X3kDQ056S%25%252Bwq9Fl1Y%25%252BTS8A%25%252FAdQ%25%253D&accept=text%2F*%3Bq%3D0.3%2C%20text%2Fhtml%3Bq%3D0.7%2C%20text%2Fhtml%3Blevel%3D1%2Ctext%2Fhtml%3Blevel%3D2%3Bq%3D0.4%2C%20*%2F*%3Bq%3D0.5 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: storagename.table.core.windows.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

**Error Response in SoapUI:**

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Content-Length: 437
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: f3375700-4002-0012-0c1d-25d9df000000
x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed
Date: Fri, 08 May 2020 09:46:33 GMT

ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>AuthenticationFailed</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:a15bcaa7-a002-001a-5f0c-25c3d0000000
Time:2020-05-08T07:43:20.2731207Z</message>
</error>
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error. I tried it with SoapUI (Community Edition) with one table in my storage account and it didn't give me an error. I had to add "Accept" request header though. Can you share more details? Are you running both tools from the same machine? Are you using the same URL in both tools?

Comment: I am using exact same URL in both Postman and SoapUI (5.5.0). Updated the question with complete error.

Comment: Can you update your question with all the request headers you're using in your request?

Comment: done. Please check.

Comment: Sorry, no luck from my side. Not sure if you could do that but if you can share the actual SAS URL, I can give it a try one more time. Just share it in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the SAS URL. You can delete it now. I tried it just now and I am able to successfully get the data.

Comment: can you tell me what's in your Accept request header?

Comment: ok. got it. Accept was added in the Query instead of Header. Silly mistake.

Comment: If you have solved the issue, could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add accept header with the request will resolve this.

```
accept */*
```